# How should I treat gray-out area on pixcel device？

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I'm sorry that I have never see or used an actual device with android OS such as Google pixcel, but I found that gray-out area on top of screen like screen shot below.
*This is "Pixcel 4 API 30 mobile emulator" called from vsCode.

[image]

And I found this kind of dead area on Pixcel 5 emulator as well, but am not sure that this is somthing in common for all android OS.
Finally, I'd like to ask that if I should avoid something to display here or this is only emulator matters and do not have to care about this ?

In case that  I have to care this area with developing by flutter, should I intentionally separate code or design between these kind of device and the others, as I'm usually using Iphone emulator and actual machine but have never seen this area and beleive I need not to care this kind of area and adopting top-margin for this problem.

Thanks for your helpful comment.

Code Added:

```
class holder extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    ref.watch(_modalProvider );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            // flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),//should I do this to avoid this area?
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 40,
              // color: Colors.grey,
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Image.asset('images/flutter.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              Folders(
                name: "list",
                subTitle: null,
              ),
            ],
          )
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: 50.0,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.search_sharp,
            color: MyStyle.mainColor,
            ),
          onPressed: () {
              ref.read(_modalProvider.notifier).update((state){
              showTopModalSheet<String?>(context, DumyModal());
            });
            
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include sample snippet. try to wrap with safeArea widget

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment and please refer to the code added above !

Comment: Tried with SafeArea?

Comment: Oh, finally I got what you meant and solved with SafeArea Widget!

Comment: yap, my bad, forgot to mention  `Widget` word

Comment: I'm sorry misunderstood some part. I could hide the area with the widget, but Emre Faruk KOLAÇ says, in case using Scaffold widget, it doesnt matter cause rendering start from the part below. But actually the logo is overlapped by the area as shown in screenshot//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That area will be also visible in real devices so you should take that area into consideration. But `Scaffold` widget will start the rendering from below that point so you don't have to think about it.
İf you want to change color of that area, you can

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.white),
    child: SafeArea(
           Scaffold:...
        )
)
```

It also effects IOS and Android devices differently, I believe that is why it is only visible in some devices

Comment: Thanks for your comment but, I've just confused. As I showed my code and screen shot above, in spite of using Scaffold widget, the flutter logo.png is overlapped by the area ?
If the comment, "Scaffold widget will start the rendering from below that point so you don't have to think about it",  is ture, why is it overlapped ? is that problem of height or layout itself ?

Comment: And undertood like, if it confuse me, I can hide it with wrapping by SafeArea Widget, right ?

Comment: You're right, it's my bad. I usually used `ListVİew` and it adds padding automatically. You just need to wrap it with `SafeArea` then.

Comment: Yeah exactly. `SafeArea` also helps you out with UI components that newer Iphones have like that bottom line, so that your widgets are not overlapping with system functions

Comment: Do you mean wrap the ListView with SafeArea ? but it is still overlapped...

Comment: Oh, when I wapped first Column with SafeArea() it worked !

Comment: Yes just wrap Column or Scaffold. ListView adds this automatically so there is no need.

Comment: I have no idea why this is not comes as a default

Comment: Thanks a lot, and finally i could solve my problem. May I ask the simple question like. this area, especially in android OS, is it called Status Bar ? or wrong

Comment: Yes it is called status bar in IOS but I don't know the name for Android

Comment: I'ts OK and I do appreciate your kindness !!!